# unable to use SaveJpeg method in windows phone 8 (NotSupportedException)

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I am using below code to save a remote image in Windows Phone 8. But i keep hitting with `System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.` exception at SaveJpeg() method call.

I tried different combinations of method call (you can see commented line). I couldn't able to figure out what i am doing incorrectly.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(imageUrl);
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // save image locally
            Debug.WriteLine("Downloading image..." + imageName);

            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("Images"))
                    myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Images");

                string path = imageName;
                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(path);

                var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };

                    bitmap.SetSource(buffer);
                    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

                    //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

                    wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 98);
                });
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting the code block in BeginInvoke block you are calling the SaveJpeg on a different thread (the "UI thread") to the code which calls `fileStream.Close()`.

In effect this means it is very likely that the call to `fileStream.Close()` will be called before `wb.SaveJpeg`.

If you move the `fileStream.Close()` inside the BeginInvoke block, after `wb.SaveJpeg()` it should work.